# torch.zeros((int(1e+12), 4)) out of memory issue

Tags: python, pytorch

I have assignment to implement Stochastic gradient descent for linear regression but keeps running out memory because of huge initialized tensor to keep track of the estimates. Is there anyway i can go around this?
this is my resource allocation `bsub -n 2 -W 3:00 -q gpuqueue -gpu num=4 -R "rusage[mem=64]" -R span[hosts=1] -Is /bin/bash` 128GB memory with 4GPUs

```
>>> betas_final, beta_bucket, expY_bucket, iter_final = run_BMAP_SGD_gpu(intercept_XY_data=intercept_XY, nMiniBatches_main=5, dev2Use = "cuda", batchSize_main=500, nIter=1e+12, rhoT=1e-3, tol=1e-6, prior_beta_var_lambda=10, add_biasX=False, optimize=False)
batch_tensor.shape: torch.Size([5, 500, 4]) created
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Prob_Models/scripts/functions_SGD_linear_Regression.py", line 155, in run_BMAP_SGD_gpu
    beta_holder = torch.zeros((int(nIter), nFeaturesX))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at alloc_cpu.cpp:117] err == 0. DefaultCPUAllocator: can't allocate memory: you tried to allocate 12000000000000 bytes. Error code 12 (Cannot allocate memory)
```

Please see my full code; the functions were in `scripts/functions_SGD_linear_Regression.py` but i've copied them here for simplicity.

```
#load modules
import torch
import torch.distributions as dist
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time as tm

def sim_XY(N, P, mu=0.0, scale=1.0, returnXY = True):
    #generate normal dist data
    m = dist.normal.Normal(torch.tensor([mu]), torch.tensor([scale]))
    X = m.sample((N,P)).squeeze().to("cuda")
    ones_column = torch.ones((X.shape[0],1)).to("cuda")
    print(f"shape ones_column, {ones_column.shape}")
    X_plusOnes=torch.hstack([ones_column, X])
    print(f"shape X_plusOnes, {X_plusOnes.shape}")
    alpha_true = dist.Normal(0.0, 1.0).sample([N]).to("cuda")
    print(f"shape X_plusOnes, {X_plusOnes.shape}")
    beta_true = dist.Normal(0.0, 1.0).sample((P+1, 1)).squeeze().to("cuda")
    print(f"beta_true.shape; {beta_true.shape}")
    sigma_true = dist.Exponential(1.0).sample().to("cuda")
    eps = dist.Normal(0.0, sigma_true).sample([N]).to("cuda")
    #y = alpha_true + X @ beta_true #+ eps #already factored in
    y = X_plusOnes @ beta_true #+ eps
    print(f"y.shape; {y.shape}")
    if returnXY is True:
        Y = y.unsqueeze(1)  # Add a dimension to make it (100, 1)
        XY = torch.cat((X, Y), dim = 1)
        print(f"XY.shape {XY.shape}\n last column is Y")
        return XY, beta_true
    else:
        return X, y, beta_true

#train and val split
def train_test_split(data, train_size, nObs_Global):
    if train_size >= 1:
        train_size = 0.8
    train_size = int(train_size * nObs_Global)
    test_size = nObs_Global - train_size
    train_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(data, [train_size, test_size])
    #train_dataset.dataset #do this to access datas
    return train_dataset, test_dataset


## Create functions for SGD linear regression BMAP
def add_bias(X):
    '''
    #func to add bias to coeffients
    '''
    ones_column = torch.ones((X.shape[0],1)).to("cuda")
    print(f"shape ones_column, {ones_column.shape}")
    X_plusOnes=torch.hstack([ones_column, X])
    print(f"shape X_plusOnes, {X_plusOnes.shape}")
    return X_plusOnes

#compute y predictions for each batch
def pred_y(computed_betas_batch, X_batch):
    y_batch_predictions = torch.matmul(X_batch, computed_betas_batch)
    return y_batch_predictions

# (yTrue - y_hat)X
def residualsPerBatch(X_batch, y_batch_predictions, y_batch_true):
    resid = torch.matmul(torch.sub(y_batch_true, y_batch_predictions), X_batch)
    return resid

#calculate the gradient
def compute_grad_allBatches(nMiniBatches_main, XY_allBatches, nObserEntireDataset,  beta_sgd, lambda_val):
    nFeaturesX = XY_allBatches.shape[2] - 1
    predictedExpectations = torch.zeros((nMiniBatches_main, XY_allBatches.shape[1])).to("cuda")
    #storeResiduals = torch.zeros((nMiniBatches_main, nFeaturesX))
    storeResiduals = torch.zeros((nMiniBatches_main, nFeaturesX)).to("cuda")
    for i in range(XY_allBatches.shape[0]):
        y_predBatch = pred_y(computed_betas_batch=beta_sgd, X_batch=XY_allBatches[i][:, :-1])
        print(f"y_predBatch.shape {y_predBatch.shape}")
        residualsBatch = residualsPerBatch(X_batch=XY_allBatches[i][:, :-1], y_batch_predictions=y_predBatch, y_batch_true=XY_allBatches[i][..., -1])
        print(f"residualsBatch.shape {residualsBatch.shape}")
        #residualsBatch=residualsBatch.detach() #Remove code to work on GPU
        storeResiduals[i] = residualsBatch
        predictedExpectations[i] = y_predBatch
    predictedExpectations=predictedExpectations.detach()
    #compute gradient    
    lambda_decay = (-1/torch.square(torch.Tensor([lambda_val]))).to("cuda")
    first_term = lambda_decay * beta_sgd
    second_term = (nObserEntireDataset/nMiniBatches_main) * torch.sum(storeResiduals, dim = 0)
    grad = first_term + second_term
    return grad, predictedExpectations

#main function to run SGD
def run_BMAP_SGD_gpu(intercept_XY_data, nMiniBatches_main, nIter, dev2Use = "cuda", batchSize_main=100, rhoT=0.001, tol=1e-6, prior_beta_var_lambda=1, add_biasX=False, optimize=False):
    #main function
    nObserEntireDataset = intercept_XY_data.shape[0]
    nFeaturesX = intercept_XY_data.shape[1] - 1
    iter = 1
    while iter < nIter:
      batch_XY = createBatches(XY_dataset = intercept_XY_data, batchSize=batchSize_main, nBatches=nMiniBatches_main)
      #inistialize beta
      betaRandom = torch.rand(nFeaturesX, device = dev2Use)
      beta_holder = torch.zeros((int(nIter), nFeaturesX))
      #beta_holder = torch.zeros((int(nIter), nFeaturesX), device="cuda")
      beta_holder[0] = betaRandom
      #beta_holder.shape
      print(f"batch_XY[:, :, :-1]; {batch_XY[:, :, :-1].shape}")
      print(f"beta_holder.shape; {beta_holder.shape}")
      #compute gradient; compute_grad_allBatches(nMiniBatches_main, XY_allBatches, nObserEntireDataset, nbatches, beta_sgd, lambda_val):
      gradients, expY = compute_grad_allBatches(nMiniBatches_main=nMiniBatches_main, nObserEntireDataset=nObserEntireDataset, XY_allBatches=batch_XY, beta_sgd=beta_holder[iter-1].to(dev2Use), lambda_val=prior_beta_var_lambda)
      betas = beta_holder[iter-1].to(dev2Use) + ((rhoT) * gradients) #follow stochastic gradient
      beta_holder[iter] = betas #keep track of betas
      #check for convergence with l2 norm strategy
      if iter > 1 and torch.linalg.norm(beta_holder[-1].to(dev2Use) - beta_holder[-2].to(dev2Use)) <= tol:
        print(f'Converged at iteration {iter}')
        if optimize == True:
          return iter
        else:
          return betas, beta_holder, expY, iter
      iter+=1
      print('Convergence not achieved within the specified iterations.')
      if optimize == True:
        return iter
      else:
        return betas, beta_holder, expY, iter

N = 700 #nObservations
P = 3 #n features
XY, true_betas = sim_XY(N=N, P=P, mu=0.0, scale=1.0, returnXY = True)

#split data into train and test
train_dataset, test_dataset = train_test_split(data=XY, train_size=0.8, nObs_Global=XY.shape[0])
train_dataset.dataset.shape

#
intercept_XY = train_dataset.dataset
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
#run sgd linear regression 
betas_final, beta_bucket, expY_bucket, iter_final = run_BMAP_SGD_gpu(intercept_XY_data=intercept_XY, nMiniBatches_main=5, dev2Use = "cuda", batchSize_main=500, nIter=1e+10, rhoT=1e-5, tol=1e-6, prior_beta_var_lambda=10, add_biasX=False, optimize=False)
```

Comment: No, there is no "workaround", you either request less memory, or you get more RAM, the amount of RAM you are requesting is insane (tens of thousands of GBs)

Comment: 12000000000000 bytes is 12 terabytes.